# PostgreSQL backward intersection & join

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a survey form of certain questions for a certain facility. 
the facility can be monitored(data entry) more than once in a month.
now i need the latest data(values) against the questions 
but if there is no latest data against any question i will traverse through prior records(previous dates) of the same month.

i can get the latest record but i don't know how to get previous record of the same month id there is no latest data.

i am using PostgreSQL 10.

Table Structure is

[image]

Desired output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to make it.

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'MON') month, 
       facility,
       idquestion,
       value
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY facility,idquestion ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
    FROM T
) t1
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7cea08ffe5031a7a6bb250807bbeb450)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    to_char(qdate, 'MON'),
    facility,
    idquestion,
    first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY facility, idquestion ORDER BY qdate DESC) as value
FROM questions
ORDER BY facility, idquestion
```

Using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

1. `first_value(value) OVER ...` gives you the first value of a window frame. The frame is a group of `facility` and `idquestion`. Within this group the rows are ordered by date DESC. So the very last value is first no matter which date it is
2. `DISTINCT` filtered the tied values (e.g. there are two values for `facility == 1` and `idquestion == 7`)

---

**Please notice:**

"date" is a reserved word in Postgres. I strongly recommend to rename your column to avoid certain trouble. Furthermore in Postgres lower case is used and is recommended.

Comment: @MuhammadSuhaib Is this what you expected? Then please don't forget to upvote any helpful answer and accept the final right one to close the topic :)